# Is there any way to remove and addListener based on a timer?

Tags: actionscript-3

How would i go about disabling the controls for a character for 5 seconds after they've hit an object and then immediatly afterwards allowing the character to move freely? So far, i've been able to get the code for the hitTest done and the removing keyboard controls (the easy part) but now i'm stumped as to how i would set the keyboard controls on a timer. Any help? My code for the hitTest and removing of controls is as follows.

```
if (player.hitTestObject(folder))
{
    trace("success!");
    addChild(myInfo);
    //stops player movement
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,kD);
}
else
{
    addChild(myInfo);
    removeChild(myInfo);
}
```

The other problems in the code are of no concern right now (such as the add/remove child in the else function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private var m_tmr:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);

private function someFunc():void
{
    if (player.hitTestObject(folder))
    {
        trace("success!");
        addChild(myInfo);
        //stops player movement
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,kD);
        m_tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
        m_tmr.start();
    }
    else
    {
        addChild(myInfo);
        removeChild(myInfo);
    }
}

private function onTimer(pEvent:TimerEvent):void
{
    m_tmr.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kD);
}
```

Adding/removing the timer's event listener each time is for purposes of efficiency; it's not critical that you keep adding/removing it like that.

Comment: The only problem that i'm having with your solution is it forces me to hold down a movement key before it allows movement again; any ideas on how to fix that? If not, thanks anyways! You're still a lifesaver! :b

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Well, my character hits the object and then stops moving but only continues moving if i hold down a key for 5 seconds, rather than moving after 5 seconds in general. I should also note that this is done with frame scripting rather than classes (bad idea, I know).

Comment: Are you wanting him to automatically start moving again, whether or not you're pressing/holding the button down at that point?  Does he start moving again if you just wait about 5-10 seconds and then press the button, instead of holding it down?

Comment: No, i want the user of the program to control his movement and allow the user to move the player the moment he presses down on the button (after waiting the 5 seconds of course) and the player only moves after the collision if i hold down the button for the 5 seconds (or however long the timer is).

Comment: Could you show your code please for kD() and for a KeyUp handler if you have one?  Sorry, I'm partially trying to find where to look.

Comment: A friend of mine got it working earlier today! (If your interested in how he did it, he reworked it so that a event would pop up instead of just text!) The thing i was trying to do was create a folder that would display a information for a question later on but my friend kind of just combined the thing so yeah, happy days! :b Anyways, enough rambling! Thank you so SO much for your help! I greatly appreciate it! :D